# Is 'r' in Br/Amr pronunciation of Arjmand (Persian word) silent?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, british-english, silent-letters, rhoticity

Is 'r' in Br/Amr pronunciation of 'Arjmand' (Persian word) silent?

(In other words, how is this word pronounced in Br/Amr English?)

Comment: Arjmand is not an English word, so I can only guess how it's pronounced in English. The 'r' should be silent in the British pronunciation (because the Brits drop all 'r's after vowels), but maybe not in the American pronunciation.

Comment: @Peter Shor, Thanks, that's what I'm looking for (how En speaker pronounced it).

Comment: However, Britains will also have different pronunciations of non-English words than Americans, from counties formerly of the British Empire.  In these cases, the British pronunciations are usually closer to the native pronunciations. See, American vs British pronunciations of Pakistan.

Comment: @Sam: On the other hand, Americans pronounce Spanish words more accurately that Brits (for example, you put the accent on the wrong syllable of *orégano*) . It just depends on which foreign countries you interact with more.

Comment: @Peter, I never said that I was British or American:), and I don't deny there are some foreign words that Americans pronounce more accurately than Brits. But Oregano comes to english from the latin origanum, through italian origano, which is pronounced more like the Brits do.

Comment: @Sam: that's not what [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=oregano&searchmode=none) says. Also *oregano* is accented on the same syllable in Italian and Spanish. But it's possible that England first got the word *origan* from French, which would indeed put the accent on the last syllable, and when *origan* was replaced by *oregano,* the accent stayed on *-gan-*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether or not you are speaking American English or British English.

American English uses the rhotic 'r', while British English 'r' is non-rhotic.

For example, rhotic speakers say "barn", and 'r' has a strong nasal sound, whereas non-rhotic speakers say "barn" pretty much like "bahn".

So "Arjmand" could be pronounced "Arjmand" or "Ajmand"

Comment: Oh, thanks! I think that's why I wasn't able to guess what to go with (as non native En speaker). There is also a Wikipedia entry about it: [Rhotic and non-rhotic accents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents)

Comment: So, is the non-rhotic accent something that the British worked out to avoid being harangued for pronunciation of 'r' in *French* words?

Comment: I have no idea. I think it was just the natural way they spoke.

Comment: Actually, there are large swaths of the USA that are non-rhotic as well. See the maps at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents . The little areas on the East Coast may look small, but contain most of the east coast Megaopolis.

Comment: Much of Northern England is rhotic too. I, as an Irish non-rhotic speaker, am odd. I blame my English parents and BBC Radio 4.

Comment: @T.E.D. Those maps are for "some _rural_" accents, which are becoming less and less common. The great great majority of AmE speakers of any variety are rhotic.

Comment: @Mitch - That is what the link says for SAE. But it doesn't say that for the non-rhotic accents in the US NorthEast (you could still be right, but if so its news to me). But if you think AAVE is going away any time soon, you're dreaming.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, in the Boston area there is some remaining non-rhoticity, but that is a small set. As to AAVE, I totally forgot that. I would claim that that is the only remaining significant non-rhotic variety and because of its size not likely to go away (maps don't show non-regional varieties).

Comment: @Mitch - It isn't just AAVE's size. Its also its cultural currency. It is the dialect of the vast majority of American music styles. My skepticisim from the rest I suppose comes from personal experience. I have an aunt who speaks non-rhotic SAE, and my father-in-law speaks non-rhotic Boston. I grew up in an AAVE part of my town. So you can perhaps forgive me for believing non-rhoticity in the USA is actually rampant.

Comment: @T.E.D. AlI know about anything in life I learned from TV. I blame them. (but, inferring from what is not said, it seems that at least in your family non-rhoticity stands out as special). And for arguments sake, a large part of American culture, though not as mainstream, is country-western music which stands out in English speaking music genres for being jarringly rhotic.

Comment: @Mitch - Yes, I'd put country, bluegrass, folk, and more niche things like perhaps Zydeco (shouldn't count either way, since its in French) in that category. Do be aware that many will argue that modern "Country" isn't really C&W but whitewashed pop (in which case the "jarring" rhoticity may be part of the point). These are the kinds of arguments a person can get into here in Oklahoma...

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is actually a bit of a misguided question, as that isn't even how the name is "spelled" in Persian. They have [their own alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perso-Arabic_script). If someone decided to write the word as `Arjmand`, they presumably picked the letters for the benefit of English speakers, and presumably meant it to be pronounced roughly as written.